# Careers ad shows caged toddler without access to food or water, in reach of open shoes

Tags: discussion, jobs, advertising

Here is the ad:

[image]

Some (including myself) have found the ad to be somewhat offensive (it's quite weird to say the least). Though I recognize the symbolic nature of the ad (staying at home yet working at the same time), the baby looks quite old (especially to still be wearing diapers).

What's worse is the fact that this ad seems to convey that children can be ignored while parents are occupied with something else (very poor timing considering [Jeff Atwood's farewell notice](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/02/farewell-stack-exchange.html)).

Not only that but the child is right next to (what appears to be) the power cables for the two PCs - a serious electrical shock hazard.

Could we maybe make some adjustments to the ad?

Comment: Its definitely weird, although I wouldn't go so far as to say "offensive". **But** as a big brother of three, all of the stuff mentioned in your third paragraph just makes me shudder, and I'm sure it must be worse for parents. :S

Comment: Yeah, "offensive" is probably too strong. "Objectionable" or "poor taste" might be better.

Comment: @jrg I feel the same way as a parent.

Comment: The real problem is the inconsistent lighting and the shared 40 on the desk.  Who shares 40's, seriously?

Comment: I thought they were using the babby as a power strip.  BOOM!  There you go, now it's offensive.

Comment: The baby and parents do not caste shadows.. Am I to understand only vampire couples with offspring get the convince of working from home? However the ad makes much more sense if you take the position that they *are* vampires.... just saying..

Comment: Also, why the cruelty.. Give the baby his toys, don't place them **just** out of reach.

Comment: @Oded: Fixed - I've switched to imgur now

Comment: @rlemon: Maybe the parents and the baby _are_ the light sources.  As an Illuminous-American, I find your assumption that everyone without a shadow is a vampire to be offensive!

Comment: It's a creative ad. Obviously Stack Exchange isn't advocating caged children with no shadows. It's just showing that you an work from home where you might have [one of these](http://i.imgur.com/8Jkp1.jpg). It's an advert not an instruction manual.

Comment: @GeorgeEdison - Was due to my ad blocker... call it a senior moment on my behalf.

Comment: The real problem is the dude is using a mouse with his left hand...and therefore is obviously a witch. /cc: @MattSherman

Comment: @David I find people without shadows who deny being a vampire offensive.... argue that!

Comment: @JasonPunyon: Well they also don't have keyboards but that's not the point.

Comment: @JasonPunyon left handed people are also vampires.. witch AND vampire?!?! sounds like something on WB

Comment: @GeorgeEdison no they do, shadowed by their monitors.

Comment: Sometimes an ad is just an ad.

Comment: @rlemon: That's the PC!

Comment: @Mark Trapp: Take your reasonable debate elsewhere, sir. Perhaps Iceland.

Comment: @GeorgeEdison they're using imacs.

Comment: @rlemon: Challenge accepted. As an Illuminous-American, I can trace my heritage all the way back to when the light first shined on this continent. (It was many years later that people arrived, completing the union of my heritage.) Not once in all of those, um, "light" years did we ever encounter a vampire. Indeed, we were persecuted for generations because of stereotypes like that. There's even strong evidence to suggest that the origins of that particular legend of vampires not having shadows originated in early Western European legends about my ancestors, before the light crossed the ocean.

Comment: @David you're presumptions that 'light' 'made it's way' gives the feeling that you're pushing intelligent design. Your religious overtones offend me.

Comment: @rlemon: **PLEASE** don't start that debate here.

Comment: @GeorgeEdison ohh i'm not... just taking the win.

Comment: @rlemon: Bah, modern-day nonsense. I'm not proud of my human-ancestors' interpretations of "the light." But what can one expect from a society that's only ever lived on _one_ little planet? While my particular branch of light-ancestors do come from Sol (with a little mix of Proxima Centauri, though I don't celebrate Proximal holidays or anything like that), the family itself traces back to the early days of the universe when our particles were at war with the anti-particles that nearly-equally emerged from the big bang. You should see our memorial to that war. It's enormous.

Comment: sans serif offends me. mono man, mono.

Comment: @AdamDavis: But look at the upvote / downvote ratio for this question.

Comment: the baby suffers from [Gigantism](http://www.nlm.nih.gov/medlineplus/ency/article/001174.htm)

Comment: also, the computers are clearly bio-kinetically powered by the baby...

Comment: I agree with @BilltheLizard. It has a touch of Matrix.

Comment: @rlemon: The man is casting a shadow.  The woman does not because women don't cast shadows.  The baby is a half breed, and so only casts them during the brightest part of the day.  And they sparkle.

Comment: @Won't the mans shadow, if relative to the light source, should be caste directly in front of him.

Comment: **AM I THE ONLY PERSON TO COMMENT ON THEM NOT HAVING FACES!!!** are they Victims of [the Wire](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/The_Wire)?

Comment: @rlemon: THERE IS A TRAITOR AMONG US!  Immediately hunt him down and put a steak through his heart.  Preferably ribeye.

Comment: I really wish I had the rep to downvote you for taking this far far far too seriously - I often put my children in a box under the stairs next to the fusebox and they seem just fine...

Comment: I really wish I could downvote comments.

Comment: Of all the things to complain about...it's like the woot! advert all over again.

Comment: The ad was hilarious, it was obviously cartoony/hipster style... BAH Politically-Correct wimps! I could understand if the baby was upside-down in a toilet... but the baby is just in a data0structure. OHWELL LET's BRING OUT THE TELETUBBY ADs

Comment: Just saw this due to @random's bump so I'm late to the game. That said, the baby's pose is weird, but way to load the discussion by calling what looks like a crib or baby gates a cage... sure, they are kinds of cages or fences just like putting a baby in a car seat is putting them in restraints. That being said, what is going on with the power cords?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

We took the ad down. Thanks for your prompt feedback. To that end, do you have any creative ideas that we could use?

Comment: I liked that ad.

Comment: I think tweaking the ad a bit would suffice. Remove the baby from the 'cage' and put him/her in a highchair next to mom (or something similar). Make the bottle look less like alcohol. Give them shadows (although not important if the shadow impaired wish to use the service).

Comment: Yes, maybe the baby should look less ignored - a highchair would be a lot better.

Comment: A high chair with a built-in computer, which the baby is using?

Comment: After some thinking, I can see George's point somewhat. The message the illustration conveys is a bit weird. George is also totally entitled to express his views here. However, I think it's a  *huge* mistake to take it down because of this Meta question. It's a nicely executed ad and it's up and running, and if there's some community feedback you can change the ad, but don't take it down because a few people express their dismay. If you create that precedent, you will find that somebody will try to shoot down *every* ad that isn't completely boring. Please don't do this.

Comment: I think the baby should be gnawing on the computer wires under the desk.  That's what they normally do, right?

Comment: @Won't Until they figure out scissors.

Comment: I think the baby should be working too. Babies are so lazy.

Comment: As a general rule, you probably shouldn't ask a question to the community in your answer to another person's question.  If you want feedback, you should post that as a *separate* question to meta so that you can take advantage of the tools inherent to all posts on the Stack Exchange network (upvoting, accepted answers, tags, etc).

Comment: @alison - If we come up with a really clever idea do we get free stackOverflow swag? PrettyPLEASE :)!

Comment: I have an idea: a dude/tte sitting under a waterfall of little blocks with 1's and 0's on them. At the top of the water is a stack-looking object coming out of a tunnel .   I should draw it?

Comment: It's back up now... http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/198462/191410

Answer (score 49):

As a father of (the world's cutest) 2 year old little girl, I have to say that I didn't find the ad offensive in the least.  It's fairly obvious what the point was, and it was cleverly executed.  Though I did find it pretty inaccurate.  Working from home with a child in the house is simply impossible if you're any kind of responsible parent.

If you *really* want to get the work-from-home point across, and have it appeal to developers, tweak the ad and have a guy sitting in his boxers on the couch, with a laptop in front of him.     Who the hell wears a tucked-in polo shirt when working from home?  *That* was the only potentially offensive part of the ad.

Comment: put the kid to work. "Here johnny, lick these envelopes for the next two hours"

Comment: *"Here johnny, clean up this data layer a bit - previous developer liked to select n + 1 for some reason"*

Comment: @AdamRackis You should realize that Johnny was the one to write it that way the first time. Toddlers often had a hard time with a zero referenced system, especially if you started them out in basic (which I consider a severe instance of child abuse, and can only hope you haven't made that particular mistake).

Comment: @AdamD - Worry not, I'm starting my daughter out with Ruby / JavaScript.  By the time she grows up I anticipate the corporate world will be a more mature place—less dependent on heavy frameworks.

Comment: And here I thought **I** had the world's cutest 2 year old girl. Are we gonna have to have a cute-off? ;)

Comment: @AdamRackis I have notified the Family and Children Services that you have been teaching your kids Ruby. *looks away in disgust*

Comment: [THUNDERDOME!](http://www.funnyordie.com/videos/5d3ef3d2fd/stay-at-home-dad-built-baby-thunder-dome)

Comment: @rlemon - I'm a career C# developer.  But my god, Ruby is a beautiful language.

Comment: @AdamD - explain?

Comment: @AdamRackis How else would you hold a cute-off?

Comment: @AdamD - sorry - missed the link - I guess it's Friday.  FUNNY!

Comment: I don't think it was offensive, but damn, that is a *strange* (and by strange, I mean *really* strange) ad.

Comment: @AdamRackis [What is wrong with Ruby](http://www.google.ca/?q=what%20is%20wrong%20with%20ruby) i'll let you pick the article.

Comment: @rlemon - I'll look forward to reading some of these.  I'm no ruby apologist - I've barely played with it.  I just liked a lot of the ruby syntax.  And I know that a lot...A LOT of asp.net MVC features were "borrowed" from Rails.

Comment: *looks at his PHP code he is currently working on*.. I really can't comment. :P

Comment: @AdamRackis I'm sure you missing it had nothing to do with me editing the link in later... (>_>)

Comment: @AdamD - good to know I have a modicum of sanity left :)

Comment: @AdamRackis I keep what's left of my sanity in a jar at home.  It's way too risky bringing that stuff to work...

Comment: As someone who works full-time from home, I agree (especially about the boxers) - with the big caveat that your "impossible" line obviously only applies if you are actually meant to be the responsible adult. Sounds pedantic, but didn't come across in the answer - *someone* has to properly look after little-one, sure.

Comment: @Marc - obviously indeed.  If you've got a significant other to look after the little one, then naturally—you're good to go.  Congrats on working from home full time! :)

Comment: I agree the ad is cryptic. We need to make it more photorealistic!  http://d24w6bsrhbeh9d.cloudfront.net/photo/3449066_460s.jpg

Comment: Gah, @Pekka, that ad's just depressing.