# Didn't we stop kicking the baby in the ads for Careers?

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, advertising

So I came across this just now:

[image: kicking the baby for Careers]

(Note the timestamp above)

It was on this question when I saw it:

[Represent JSON Array into String](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11872840/50776)

That said, [this ad was taken down](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/122713/140951) a while ago.

I consider it a bug that it's still being shown.

Note, this is in no way about my opinion on the matter (I have none, really), it's about an obvious contradiction (hence being tagged [bug](/questions/tagged/bug)).

Comment: They probably adopted a new one

Comment: Hey, my parents kicked me and I'm just... wait, what was I saying?

Comment: @jonsca for the last time I'm not your parent, that's why I keep kicking you

Comment: So *that's* why my answer on the original baby-kicking ad is suddenly getting attention...

Comment: @BenBrocka So it's one of those `A => B`, `B' => A'` type situations?

Comment: @AdamRackis Ah-ha, so people who live in glass desk-playpen combinations shouldn't throw the first kick? (to mix two idioms)

Comment: [RELATED](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zkcNLtn2gtk)

Comment: Babies are an often overlooked source of electricity.

Comment: +1 for freehand circle

Comment: Maybe they changed their shoes for slippers. They don't bruise as much.

Comment: I wish *my* wife would work with me like that.

Comment: Still trying to figure out why the toys are *outside* the playpen

Comment: @waxeagle The toys are for the parents.  Look at it, does it *look* like they care about the kid?  Hells no.

Comment: @waxeagle If we're nitpicking, the shadows are *way* off...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This ad did in fact run about 11k impressions on 8/8 - this was the day we were doing some troubleshooting with the server, and it looks as if this ad was accidentally enabled and then disabled. It hasn't served since and it remains inactive so it won't serve EVER AGAIN. :) If anyone spots it again, please let me know!

Comment: ...but did kicking babies convert?

Comment: This is a bit unclear.  We were told it was taken down, and then it was served again.  Now you are saying that it will *never* serve again, but if it does, let you know.  That's a bit of a mixed message.

Comment: @casperOne The ad was "disabled" in our server, so when our friends at AdZerk were making a fix, they "enabled" and then "disabled" the ad again - a simple error. I'm asking for anyone to point out if they see it again, just in case the error wasn't isolated, I count on the users to help me out so we maintain an awesome site!

Comment: @Jginger Thanks for the clarification, much appreciated.

Comment: @Jginger While we have your attention, we're genuinely curious if that ad converted at all for the 11K impressions you got.  I mean, if the ad works, then perhaps the baby should be sacrificed in the name of the site.

Comment: @casperOne- The ad actually had a 0.21% CTR, which is quite high, but its only about 24 clicks over the 11K impressions- given the strong response to the ad the first time we ran it, I'm not sure this is worth a reversal.

Comment: @Jginger Wasn't asking for one, but rather, wanted to know out of curiosity.  Thanks for the response, it's always nice to see how things like this work inside of SE.

Comment: I spotted it again today. http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/198462/191410

Comment: I spotted it also here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/887029/how-to-implement-confirmation-dialog-in-jquery-ui-dialog?lq=1