# Is it possible to remove the Careers banner with the dying starfish?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, advertising

Is it possible to remove the annoying ad with the dying starfish?

Certainly, this is not what my career should feel like.

[image]

Comment: Oh yeah, and the sand...I mean, if that stuff gets into your keyboard. Or what about the salty water. That can't be good... And how is this a bug exactly?

Comment: @Bart Feel free to retag this :) I could not find a suitable category for this

Comment: Dying starfish is certainly a step up from [kicking the baby](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142762/didnt-we-stop-kicking-the-baby-in-the-ads-for-careers).

Comment: Don't you have more important things to complain about, like pluralization bug?

Comment: I see nothing wrong with this ad... I'd love a job that felt like I was lying on the beach.  I think most users (myself included) would never put the 2+2 together that this creature is actually dying.

Comment: @scunliffe *"I'd love a job that felt like I was lying on the beach."* ...yeah, as if that is the message they tried to convey.

Comment: @minitech shall I [clean off my giant S?](https://twitter.com/codinghorror/statuses/1165936105)

Comment: Oh how I wish I had been more active on meta so I could vote the reworks below.

Comment: @Joel - can we know what is planned, or will this be a surprise? :)

Comment: I have seen this on the site today. Looks good! @Joel: Would you please change to `status-completed`?

Comment: Whoa. Oh boy, do you know what this means? This is a precedent! Stand by to be overflowed with user suggestions for each and every other ad on the site!

Comment: Huh. I thought this was just a strange joke.

Answer (score 185, accepted):

To address this issue, I suggest the immediate casting of a new, less lackluster starfish.  I propose this fellow:

[image: This is what your career should feel like. If you're a starfish.]

---

**Justice has been done!** The SE Director of Marketing contacted me last night and the *super*-starfish has been [signed for a modelling contract](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jVaTS.jpg) with Stack Overflow.

Comment: Add a monocle and we have a winner.

Comment: @Bart and a handlebar moustache?

Comment: Mmmm...indubitably

Comment: Dahling, you look mahvelous!

Comment: Distant cousin of Mr. Peanut?

Comment: [This is actually *now in rotation*, I kid you not!](http://i.stack.imgur.com/mRS2z.png)

Comment: Though without the monocle....will they never learn?

Comment: I think it's pretty clear that a monocle would have make this feel *just a little bit silly*, no?

Comment: I was about to remind people that it doesn't have eyes for a monocle ... then I remembered the martini glass

Comment: -1 too much ideologically capitalistic.. as if money would mean happiness!.... very sad

Answer (score 66):

Yeah. And there's a lot more wrong with that ad than just that.

- The orange of the starfish is potentially offensive for people who don't like dutch royalty and/or victims of the [Orange Free State](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orange_Free_State).
- the Careers logo looks like the reception bars on your mobile phone; the fact that there's six bars could make people from rural areas with bad reception feel inferior. Did anybody think of that when dreaming this up in their fancy New York office?
- the "this is what your career should feel like" text is hovering above the water. Are you insinuating that my career is supposed to *sink*? Or that it is about to sink?
- regarding showing careers ads in general. Isn't this sending the message that my career isn't going exactly as it should? How dare you suggest such a thing?

Comment: And what did they do to the starfish? Cover it in Doritos flavouring? That's animal abuse surely.

Comment: Don't forget to mention that obnoxious "by stackoverflow" tagline. Like the rest of the network doesn't exist.

Comment: To be fair, the starfish is on a small mound of sand, a positive! It's getting ahead in the world!

Comment: @Ben a mound? That's symbolic of a tumor, a pustule, a boil just waiting to explode. Thanks, I missed that. It makes things even worse!!!!

Comment: @Pekka Don't worry, it's a mound for sure.... a SACRIFICIAL MOUND!!

Comment: FWIW: I've had better cell reception in the middle of Nebraska than I did in NYC... This ad is offensive to city-dwellers also!

Comment: For your second point the having more bars merely shows a more accurate representation of the true signal strength.  Signal strength is still 0-100%, so having 6 bars allows the carrier to show in increments of 16% while 5 only shows 20% (less accurate) increments.  So no need for people to get offended over this.

Comment: @Atlos but what if I'm in an area that never gets more than 2-3 bars?

Comment: @Pekka Well the reception percentage will be the same, but the phone can have a variable amount of bars to represent that number.  So the (bar : insecurity) relationship can vary depending on your phone.  I've heard that iPhones have up to 20 bars to represent signal strength to make users feel superior to Android users.

Comment: I am dutch, and I am offended by orange (especially during soccer season)

Comment: @Gamecat Luckily we have nothing to do with this Orange Free State thingy.... *reads article*.... nevermind.

Comment: @Bart, history hurts.

Answer (score 60):

I suppose if you're the sort of person who identifies with the *starfish*, you could take it badly.

But what if you identify with the *viewer*: the overlord staring down on the starfish, which is withering in the hot rays of your unbridled contempt!

Yes, what if your career is that of a *senior developer*, and the starfish is one of your unworthy minions! The starfish is gasping, *begging*, to drink in the delicious seawater of your knowledge? Your career is to *pick up* that sad, startled, starving starfish and place him lovingly back into the ocean of your vast experience -- leaving behind the unblemished beachfront of pristine architecture

It's all in how you look at things.

Comment: Best. Analogy. Ever.

Comment: This is so goood

Comment: If you identify with the starfish then you should probably find a new job immediately.

Answer (score 33):

Having looked at this for a while, I can see [how this is offensive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sg6C0.jpg) in oh so many ways. For the sake of being constructive, how about a more neutral alternative:

[image: But how about the light oppressing the dark? Or or...pfff]

Surely you can't find any fault with that....

Comment: `This is what your career should feel like` followed by a bottom bar in the colour of crap, yeah, nothing at fault with that.

Comment: @YannisRizos Admittedly some of my feelings on my career might shine through there. But can you really blame an artist for a display of personality?

Comment: But this whole thread is about blaming an artist for personality...

Comment: How strange. @BenBrocka seems unaffected by my mind trick....

Comment: This would be better if there was a "Please fill in blank line below: ______________________"

Comment: @animuson All content is CC-BY-SA....go for it

Comment: Damn it guys! My carrer should not look like an empty square! Why not add something nice like a beach and a symbol that would definitely make it look like holidays, this would be awesome!

Comment: @VincentRobert You might have something there....white sand...a starfish perhaps? I mean, I'm just throwing out wild ideas, but that might just work...

Comment: @Bart - It's still missing a compelling "call to action".  A big gray button labelled "Get Started" perhaps?

Comment: @mootinator Damn, we're on a roll here. I'll contact SO's marketing department. We are sure hires.

Answer (score 22):

I was walking along the beach one day and I noticed a boy in the distance. When I got closer, I saw that there were thousands of dying starfishes on the beach and he was throwing them one by one back into the sea.

I said "There are thousands of starfish and you'll never be able to save them all"

Then he started throwing them at me

Comment: +1 for story well told even though it got nothing to do with the question!

Comment: [Say the starfish story again!](http://cdn.memegenerator.net/instances/400x/24257906.jpg)

Comment: @Bart what's the cultural background for that meme? Is this starfish story retold over and over again in the US?

Comment: Here's the original story http://www.starrbrite.com/starfish.html

Comment: @örs I have no clue. I just remembered having seen the image and it seemed to fit the occasion. :)

Comment: Here's the original original story: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Star_Thrower

Answer (score 20):

I'm not a fan of the orange.  In Canada, that could be misinterpreted as support for the NDP party.  As such, I'm recommending a design which doesn't favour any particular color over another.  This way we can appear politically neutral and avoid any sort of pointless controversy.

Also, the font should suggest my career should be a little more fun, don't you think?

[image]

Comment: Not double...not all the way....I'm not sure I can support this.

Comment: Not even *rainbows* are politically neutral anymore.

Comment: joke's on you because hipsters have moved on from Comic Sans hatin to Papyrus hatin now.

Comment: +1 - There's no way this could possibly offend anyone at all.

Comment: I want my career to feel like riding on the proverbial rainbow-emitting unicorn, can't you show that?

Comment: In the US this means something TOTALLY different....

Comment: you did us the favour of proving you were Canadian, I like that :)

Comment: @GatesVP Oops, apparently I politely misspelled *colour* for the benefit of the US audience, and let *favour* get past me.  How *gauche*.

Comment: Where's pink? And black? Are you trying to say something here? Something *offensive*!?

Comment: Haven't you heard? There is no pink light: http://youtu.be/S9dqJRyk0YM, of course, there's also no black light, so he's really just trying to offend things that don't emit light :)

Answer (score 17):

Yes, of course it's dying. Starfish out of water, like any fish out of water, need to be thrown back into the sea as soon as possible. All they can do is lie there, hoping that someone will rescue them! What's pleasant about that?
Therefore, I propose this. Much, much better.

[image: Same as above, except under water]

Or if they mean your career should feel like the kind of holiday where you do nothing but lie on the beach all day, well, these things get old really soon, and make you itch (as does the sand) for going back to your real job, doing real things again.

Or do they want you to identify with a the life of a starfish, having only your five paws to type with, thinking in base five and having a hard time with numbers in base ten?

I mean, they can't just mean that your career should feel like a starfish, do they? I'm not entirely sure what a starfish feels like, but I'm quite certain I don't want my job to feel like that.

No, not a good ad.

Comment: I don't know about this one. Those sea urchins look pointy. They seem to represent the looming consequences of the slightest wrong move.

Comment: Down on the cold ocean floor, hoping that even the slightest ray of sunlight will reach you to illuminate what can only be described as a dark watery grave... I like it

Comment: Starfish are mobile, they bury themselves most of the time.

Comment: Be careful about throwing starfish in the water; many of them are venomous.

Answer (score 17):

Also a starfish:

If your carreer feels like:

[image]

try [this](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/)

Comment: Nice site but the only location option is **FINLAND**

Comment: This would be perfect if he was using a [slightly different hammer](http://www.flickr.com/photos/raindrift/sets/72157629492908038/)

Answer (score 14):

In the interest of addressing concerns that the above ads focus excessively on careers, I have mocked up the following ad:

[image]

Comment: From the two I prefer the white one on the right.

Comment: this color offends me deeply.

Comment: Oh I see, so your career should feel like you're being smothered by Caucasians?

Answer (score 12):

### Isn't it what your career should feel like?

[image: Isn't it what your career should feel like?]

Comment: This *is* what my career feels like sometimes.

Answer (score 5):

This one is the ultimate I think:

[image: Even better]

Comment: My thoughts on that? Entirely neutral. Well done good Sir.

Comment: Doesn't this discriminate non-Caucassian people?

Comment: BOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOORING

Comment: I don’t like the color though.

Comment: a+++++ would click again

Comment: It occurs to me that the font used is not Comic Sans. You are suggesting that work should not be fun, apparently.

Comment: @maartenba Whoops, I had that thought the same time as you apparently, heh. :)

Comment: @mootinator Yeah. But rainbows mean it's raing somewhere, provoking gray feelings. Would go with a clean white background.