# What is this ad actually for?

Tags: discussion, bug, advertising, regression

It appears someone is trying to promote clouds on the network. I've seen this ad on various sites, and as a sidebar and banner style ad.

What is it for? Clicking it results in nothing but selecting a part of the ad, as can be seen in below screenshot. Which makes it clear the clouds are just made up of white circles. Is there some hidden message?

[image: strange clouds add]

### Edit:

Following the comments this appears to be a regression of this thread: [Why an image of clouds made of dots as an ad?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/292332/why-an-image-of-clouds-made-of-dots-as-an-ad)

### Edit2:

Yesterday I encountered this sort of add out in the wild on the interwebs. So it appears to be something on the advertisers side, not specifically to SO. This happened when I went to read an article from a local newspaper through facebook, which renders a sort of primitive browser within facebook.

Comment: My bet is on *Groen Links* ...

Comment: Good one @rene, But I also wouldn't be surprised if it turns out to be *D66*

Comment: Is it...cloud computing?

Comment: This is going to be [the Starfish scenario](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/143130/is-it-possible-to-remove-the-careers-banner-with-the-dying-starfish) all over again, isn't it?

Comment: might very well be @Bart, but at least the starfish was advertising something...

Comment: Already asked https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/292332/why-an-image-of-clouds-made-of-dots-as-an-ad

Comment: @AnkitSharma well then this is a regressed bug

Comment: I am really inspired by Mitchell's answer on the original question. Once I make my millions I will have to remember to pay for non-ads with pictures of my favorite animals (jerboas among them) on websites that I like

Answer (score 4):

As far as I remember (from digging into it in the past), it's a generic banner used as result of internal error.

The answer by the (former) SO developer to the linked old bug report hints that as well:

> The clouds are due to an ad tag being implemented improperly

"Implemented improperly" >>> Error >>> generic banner so there won't be an empty gap