# Weird Work From Home advert

Tags: bug, jobs, advertising

**UPDATE:**

Apparently this ad [is not new](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/122711/191410) and its relative mertis have been discussed.

But the official decision was, apparently, to remove the ad from Stack Exchange:

> [We took the ad down. Thanks for your prompt feedback. To that end, do you have any creative ideas that we could use?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/122713/191410)

Has the Careers 2.0 collective changed its mind, or was this an accident?

---

Looks like this ad was [accidentally re-activated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/142762/191410):

> [This ad did in fact run about 11k impressions on 8/8 - this was the day we were doing some troubleshooting with the server, and it looks as if this ad was accidentally enabled and then disabled. It hasn't served since and it remains inactive **so it won't serve EVER AGAIN.** :) If anyone spots it again, please let me know!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/143540/191410)
>
> *(Emphasis mine)*

---

I'm not 100% sure this is the appropriate place to discuss Careers 2.0 advertising, but I found this ad to be a bit... uh... *weird*.

[image: Working parents at desk, unsupervised baby underneath]

Are those power cables electrocuting that unsupervised baby?!? Somebody call family and children services!

Comment: Thanks @Martijn, imgur is blocked at my office.

Comment: I believe they are using its brain as a main frame; completely justifying keeping it in a baby prison

Comment: @Servy - They said they took the ad down, but I saw it today. Perhaps this needs to be reopened.

Comment: Related http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142762/didnt-we-stop-kicking-the-baby-in-the-ads-for-careers

Comment: Thanks @juergend, left a comment on the linked answer.

Comment: Just to update on this - we have poked people appropriately for it. Thanks for your diligence in reporting!

Comment: @GraceNote - Thanks for the update. (For the record, I don't find it offensive... just odd.)

Comment: It also looks like some kind of botched M.C. Escher piece.

Comment: @WesleyMurch - Hmm... maybe if the baby were crawling on the underside of the desk...